# django create method of the serializer when creating an order, gives an error Country with the name Country already exists

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have an order model, when creating an entry in the create method of the serializer, I try to add a country to the manytomany field, but I get an error: A country named Country already exists

I have models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    period = models.DateField(_('Срок выполнения'), blank=True, null=True)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(to='categories.Specialization', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='order_specializations')
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, related_name='countries', blank=True)
    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name=_("Заказчик"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_customers')


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    phone_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    flag = models.FileField(upload_to='flags/', null=True, blank=True)
    
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='countries')
```

serializers.py

```
class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    specialization_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'created_at', 'specialization_id', 'slug', 'customer', 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'country']
        read_only_fields = ['customer', 'slug']
    
    country = CountryOrderSerializer(many=True)
    
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        price = validated_data.get('price', 0)
        country_data = validated_data.pop('country', [])
        if check_customer_balance(customer=user, currency=currency, price=price):
            name = validated_data.get('name')
            specialization_id = validated_data.pop('specialization_id')
            validated_data['specialization'] = Specialization.objects.get(id=specialization_id)
            order = super().create(validated_data)
            create_order_transfer_money(user, currency, price, order)
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Not enough funds'})
        for country_info in country_data:
            try:
                country = Country.objects.get(**country_info)
                order.country.add(country_info)
            except Country.DoesNotExist:
                return Response({'error': 'Country does not exist'})
        return order
```

when I sending a post request

```
{
    "name": "order3",
    "description": "ordeadadasd",
    "specialization_id": 1,
    "country": [{"name": "test"}]   
}
```

the create method doesn't even start working. And I get the errror: A country named Country already exists
it seems to me, there is an attempt to write to the Country table, but it should be added to the table associated with the order. There is no need to write anything at all in the Country table
PLEASE HELP!)

Answer (score 0):

Mark the subserializer as read-only. A serializer should *not* construct a response, the serializer constructs *objects*.

You also should do the validation, in the validators, not the create method:

```
class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    specialization_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'price',
            'created_at',
            'specialization_id',
            'slug',
            'customer',
            'file1',
            'file2',
            'file3',
            'country',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['customer', 'country', 'slug']

    country = CountryOrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not check_customer_balance(
            customer=user, currency=currency, price=data.get('price', 0)
        ):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Not enough funds')
        country_data = self.initial_data.get('country', [])
        countries = Country.objects.get(
            name__in=[country['name'] for country in country_data]
        )
        if len(countries) != len(country_data):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid countries.')
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order = super().create(validated_data)
        create_order_transfer_money(user, currency, price, order)
        order.country.add(
            *Country.objects.filter(
                name__in=[
                    country['name']
                    for country in self.initial_data('country', [])
                ]
            )
        )
        return order
```

Comment: if I set it to read-only (read_only=True) then I don't get country data in validated_data

Comment: @РусланПрусаков: that's why we validate and use `.initial_data` for the country as specified in the answer...